# Is it possible to retrieve the RSSI of a specific AP using the the ESP32 without doing a network scan?

Tags: wifi, esp32, arduino-esp32, rssi, flipper

I'm building an AP hunting app. Is there a way to get the RSSI of an AP using the ESP32 without doing a scan of available networks and then extracting the RSSI from the list returned list? Basically, I'd like to get the RSSI of a specific selected AP without going through the scan process involved in the ESP32 library and without connecting to the network.

Comment: What do you mean by _a specific selected AP_ - how do you select this AP if you don't know its RSSI?

Comment: WiFi scanning does not connect to a network. What you want is a chicken-and-egg scenario, without scanning, you won't get the information about the AP(s). You can reduce the time for scanning if you know AP's BSSID (MAC address), but you still need to do scan, it just that you are scanning for a specific AP.

Comment: You can additionally speed up scanning by specifying the channel, if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that running a beacon scan in promiscuous mode will provide me with the RSSI at all of their beacon signals that were caught. This essentially allows me to say "give me all of the beacon signals for the input SSID and output the beacon's RSSI". This is dependent on the AP's beacon interval setting, but most are default set to 100ms.